# Memory Scanner info

Tags: c#, shared-memory

I like to add the force feedback on games that don't support it.

To do this I was thinked to intercept when the game open some specific audio wav file (ex. collision.wav , damage.wav, connon.wav, etc..)

I have tried with a memory scanner to see when the audio file will load. Here a part of code:

```
while (proc_min_address_l < proc_max_address_l)
{
    // 28 = sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)
    VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, proc_min_address, out mem_basic_info, 28);

    // if this memory chunk is accessible
    if (mem_basic_info.Protect == PAGE_READWRITE && mem_basic_info.State == MEM_COMMIT && (mem_basic_info.lType == MEM_MAPPED || mem_basic_info.lType == MEM_PRIVATE))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[mem_basic_info.RegionSize];

        // read everything in the buffer above
        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, mem_basic_info.BaseAddress, buffer, mem_basic_info.RegionSize, ref bytesRead);

        string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        if (result.Contains(TextToFind))
            MatchCount++;

        // then output this in the file
        //for (int i = 0; i < mem_basic_info.RegionSize; i++)
        //    sw.WriteLine("0x{0} : {1}", (mem_basic_info.BaseAddress + i).ToString("X"), (char)buffer[i]);
    }

    // move to the next memory chunk
    proc_min_address_l += mem_basic_info.RegionSize;
    proc_min_address = new IntPtr(proc_min_address_l);
}
```

unfortunatenly there is a problem, this code work only the first time, becouse in the memory when the time pass there are multiple match of 'TextToFind' (MatchCount) so it is not easy to detect when the game play again a wav file.

So I have thinked a solution like this:

for each memory scan I load a temp stucture array that contain information of every match (wav_name and base_address) ex:

```
Arr[0].FileName='Collision.wav';
Arr[0].BaseAdress= 54354646;

Arr[1].FileName='Collision.wav';
Arr[1].BaseAdress= 67576575;

Arr[2].FileName='Collision.wav';
Arr[2].BaseAdress= 354664;
```

after every scan I can do a check like this:

```
if (Updated_Array != Previous_Array_Copy)
  // the wav file was load
```

theorically this work ? Or there is another easy way to do this ?

Comment: Are you working in `c#` or `c++`, you should only tag the languages you are using

Comment: I would use a two dimensions array List<List<byte>> where each file is a List<byte> so you do not have to keep track of BaseAddress.

Comment: Games probably won't open the files over and over again when they need to play them...

Comment: Pattern scanning is not the best approach, you should find the PlaySound() function and hook it, when collision.wav matches your filters, then you can initiate haptic feedback.  would be easy to find referencing the collision.wav string

Comment: Thank you ! you have right I have do it and work !! one question: the next step is patch the exe (add my hook dll reference). With Cheat Engine work in memory, but not patch the exe. There is a tool that I select dll, exe file and automatically patch the exe with dll reference ?